# What was the title and who was the author of a futuristic book about baseball?

Tags: story-identification

While it wasn't great literature, several years ago (late 80's or early 90's, although I don't know how old the book was then) I enjoyed a novel that combined a couple of my favorite things, science fiction and baseball. It is set in the not too distant future. In it, a baseball fan is somehow required to pitch for his favorite team - which I think was the Chicago Cubs. My recollection is that he wore a mask or helmet to hide who he was; while he didn't do particularly well on the field personally, the team was fairly successful overall (especially for the Cubs! ;-)  Unfortunately, I don't remember a lot of other details.

Can anyone provide the title and author?

Comment: This didn't involve the guy having a "trick knee" which gave out on him mid-game, did it?

Comment: @SeanDuggan: I don't remember that, but I can't say for certain that it didn't.

Comment: I don't see your story in it, but you might like [this anthology.](https://www.sfsite.com/10b/up138.htm)

Comment: There's a list of baseball-themed SFF stories [here,](https://www.sfsite.com/~silverag/baseball.html) but mostly it's just titles and authors with a few links. Maybe something will jog your memory?

Comment: @JoeL.: Yeah, it was in there - The New AToms Bombshell by Robert Browne. Thanks! If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: @GreenMatt: Done and done. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [*The New AToms Bombshell,*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002C0JUL6) by Robert Browne.

[image]

From the [Goodreads link:](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4460424-the-new-atoms-bombshell)

> Published in 1980, The New AToms’ Bombshell is about a failing major
>   league baseball team located in Chicago. Its set in the future year of
>   2002. The owner dies and in a weird bequest leaves the team to teacher Matt Paradise for one year. Part of the deal is that he has to be a
>   starting pitcher AND disguise his identity by wearing bandages on his
>   face AND change his name! Wait…What?! He has to wear bandages on his
>   face for the entire baseball season?!

Comment: Thanks (again)! Obviously I got the team name wrong, but my recollection is that the AToms bore a strong resemblence to the Cubs.